# Give span inside p tag a class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify the DOM of some code on a number of pages, in two instances:

```html
<p class="styles_label__gDrbZ"><span><a href="/austin">Home</a></span><span>Review</span></p>
```

```html
<p class="styles_label__gJ3_z"><span><a href="/new-york">NYC</a></span><span>Guide</span></p>
```

I need to add a class of `category` to second span - so eg.

```html
<p class="styles_label__gJ3_z"><span><a href="/new-york">NYC</a></span><span class="category">Guide</span></p>
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this...

Comment: `$('p span:nth-child(2)').addClass('category');`

Comment: Why? If it's for styling you may not need to (since it's easy enough to select via CSS), if it's for event-binding with JavaScript then it's easy enough to select using CSS selectors with `document.querySelectorAll()` and so on. You don't have justify your need, but in many cases you may not need the added class-name, and it helps of we know what you're trying to do. Also, where did you get stuck, where's your attempt? What went wrong, and in what way? What help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('p').children('span').last().addClass('category')
```

i hope it was useful !